# Installing PS printer on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, printer

I have to install PS printer on Windows 8 machine. I am installing it on Windows 7 machine by following parameters to rundll32.exe following command:

```
printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "MyPrinter" /f %win%\inf\ntprint.inf /r "FILE:" /m "Gestetner C7640nD PS"
```

Its installing printer on Windows 7 successfully. But on Windows 8 its giving error message:

"Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000705).

Windows cannot locate a suitable printer driver. Contact your administrator for help locating and installing a suitable driver."

Can anybody help me to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using drivers of default Microsoft PS Class Driver to install my PS printer on Windows 8. Now I am using following command to install my printer on windows 8:
    `printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "MyPrinter" /f %win%\inf\ntprint.inf /r "FILE:" /m "Microsoft PS Class Driver"`

After using above command MyPrinter is installed successfully on Windows 8 without any error.